# Unable to start Grakn session due to keyspace problem

Tags: java, vaticle-typedb

I'm trying to reproduce the `phone_calls` example from the [Grakn examples](https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/examples/phone-calls-schema) (client Java). Althought my keyspaces list returns a valid list of keyspaces, containing the desired `phone_calls` keyspace, I'm getting an `INVALID_ARGUMENT: grakn.core.server.exception.TransactionException-Keyspace name is invalid: []. Keyspace name cannot start with a number, and can only contain maximum 48 characters of lower case, alphanumeric and underscore characters` The server logs don't reveal any other insights... Any help is highly appreciated!

```
static void connectAndMigrate(Collection<Input> inputs) throws FileNotFoundException {
      
      GraknClient client = new GraknClient("localhost:48555");

      List<String> keyspacesList = new ArrayList<String>();
      keyspacesList = client.keyspaces().retrieve();
      System.out.println(client.keyspaces().retrieve());

      GraknClient.Session session = client.session(keyspacesList.get(0));

      for (Input input : inputs) {
          System.out.println("Loading from [" + input.getDataPath() + "] into Grakn ...");
          loadDataIntoGrakn(input, session);
      }

      session.close();
      client.close();
  }
```

Comment: Can you list down the version number of Grakn and `client-java` that you're using?

Comment: I was using Grakn Core 1.5.7 and the Grakn Client for Java 1.5.0 - not an ideal combination... Problem solved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common cause for this issue is the incompatibility between the running Grakn server and the client in use. Refer to [Client Java compatibility table](http://dev.grakn.ai/docs/client-api/java#dependencies) to ensure the client you're using is compatible with the Grakn server you have running.

Comment: Upgraded my Grakn Client for Java - problem solved!